# Read product entity variants with custom fields

Tags: shopware6

I have a main product that contains custom fields all his variants inherited a custom field value from main product.

Problem is that if I read a variant entity custom fields are empty. Is there way to read custom fields for variant that is set only in main product ( inherited ).

```php
$criteria = (new Criteria());
$criteria->addFilter(new NotFilter(NotFilter::CONNECTION_OR, [new EqualsFilter('parentId', null)]));
$product = $this->productRepository->search(
            $criteria,
            Context::createDefaultContext()
        )->getEntities()->first()
var_dump($product->getCustomFields()) ;// EMPTY no inherited values from main product
```

What Kind of Query should I write to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitly set the context to consider inheritance before fetching the entities. This setting is useful because you might sometimes want to check if entities have their own values or not.

```php
$context = Context::createDefaultContext();
$context->setConsiderInheritance(true);

$product = $this->productRepository
    ->search($criteria, $context)
    ->getEntities()
    ->first();
```